# Modifiying and concatenating header titles chosen depending on body criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have the following Excel table used to calculate the overtime hours worked.

[image]

I want the last two columns to be auto-generated, preferably with formulas, so that the user can see on which dates the employees have worked OT.

The example output for Bob would be:

```
Dates worked Normal OT : "2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th, 10th & 12th"

Dates worked Double OT : "6th, 7th & 13th"
```

Please note that I don't have Excel 2016, and therefore can't use `TEXTJOIN()`. Also note that the dates for Week 1 and Week 2 are stored in number format, not date format, so the use of `WEEKDAY()` is also not possible.

---

P.S. I have already tried a `TextJoin` UDF but it doesn't seem to work since I have a lot of criteria within the formula.

The working formula for `TEXTJOIN` in Excel 2016 is this:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(WEEKDAY($B$3:$O$3,2)<6,IF($B5:$O5>0,TEXT($B$3:$O$3,"dd/mm/yyyy"),""),""))
```

This is using date formats. The UDF doesn't seem to work with these parameters.

Comment: You haven't found any of the UDFs in the [tag:textjoin] tag that mimic TextJoin? There's only ~30 Q's to go through.

Comment: Have you at least written the Select Case section of code that applies the *_st, _nd, _rd, _th* suffix to the numbers? If not, that might be somewhere to start.

Comment: First you state that the expected results are *2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th, 10th & 12th* then you state that the working formula you do not have access to involves outputting (concatenating) a series of dates as text in *dd/mm/yyyy* format. TBH, it really isn't clear exactly what you want.

Comment: Hi Jeeped. Thanks for replying. I have a working formula for Excel 2016 with TextJoin and date format. But unfortunately my workplace doesnt have licence to Excel 2016. I tried using the UDF in Excel 2013 but it did not work. Therefore I need a formula that would work in Excel 2013. Hope it is clear.

Comment: You still haven't clarified what the expected output is. Your narrative contradicts the supplied 'working formula'.

Comment: It does contradict since I explained why I am not using the UDF. I need a formula for Excel 2013 to get the output " 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th, 10th & 12th" without the use if TextJoin or the UDF.

Comment: Well, you can either do that with 31 nested IF statements (actually not as hard as it sounds) or you need to modify the existing UDF for your very specific requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I am ignoring everything in the PS at the end of your question as [Jeeped](//stackoverflow.com/users/4039065) is right in that it is contradictory to the main body and screenshot.

Without using a UDF, the formula would be much too complicated. Don't worry, I have supplied my own basic `TEXTJOIN()` UDF that definitely works.

All the following formulae need to be "array-entered" (by pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) in a **single** cell, and then copied/filled down. (Remember **not** to copy the starting `{` and ending `}`.)

The only difference in the two formulae is that one uses the comparison `<5` whilst the other uses `>=5`, and each one refers to the appropriate "No. of Days" cell.

This first formula needs to be array-entered into cell `T5` (Bob's "Dates Worked Normal OT") and then filled down:

```vbs
{=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, IF((MOD(COLUMN($B5:$O5)-COLUMN($B5), 7)<5)*($B5:$O5>0), $B$3:$O$3 & CHOOSE(IF($B$3:$O$3<4, $B$3:$O$3, IF($B$3:$O$3<21, 4, IF($B$3:$O$3<24, $B$3:$O$3-20, IF($B$3:$O$3<31, 4, 1)))), "st", "nd", "rd", "th"), "")), ", ", " & ", MAX(1, S5-1))}
```

The expanded, easier to read, version of the above formula (it will also work if you copy-paste it):

```
{=
SUBSTITUTE(
  TEXTJOIN(
    ", ",
    TRUE,
    IF(
      (MOD(COLUMN($B5:$O5)-COLUMN($B5), 7)<5)*($B5:$O5>0),
      $B$3:$O$3
      &
      CHOOSE(
        IF($B$3:$O$3<4, $B$3:$O$3, IF($B$3:$O$3<21, 4, IF($B$3:$O$3<24, $B$3:$O$3-20, IF($B$3:$O$3<31, 4, 1)))),
        "st", "nd", "rd", "th"
      ),
      ""
    )
  ),
  ", ",
  " & ",
  MAX(1, R5-1)
)}
```

This second formula needs to be array-entered into cell `U5` (Bob's "Dates Worked Double OT") and then filled down:

```
{=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, IF((MOD(COLUMN($B5:$O5)-COLUMN($B5), 7)>=5)*($B5:$O5>0), $B$3:$O$3 & CHOOSE(IF($B$3:$O$3<4, $B$3:$O$3, IF($B$3:$O$3<21, 4, IF($B$3:$O$3<24, $B$3:$O$3-20, IF($B$3:$O$3<31, 4, 1)))), "st", "nd", "rd", "th"), "")), ", ", " & ", MAX(1, S5-1))}
```

The expanded version of the above formula is:

```
{=
SUBSTITUTE(
  TEXTJOIN(
    ", ",
    TRUE,
    IF(
      (MOD(COLUMN($B5:$O5)-COLUMN($B5), 7)>=5)*($B5:$O5>0),
      $B$3:$O$3
      &
      CHOOSE(
        IF($B$3:$O$3<4, $B$3:$O$3, IF($B$3:$O$3<21, 4, IF($B$3:$O$3<24, $B$3:$O$3-20, IF($B$3:$O$3<31, 4, 1)))),
        "st", "nd", "rd", "th"
      ),
      ""
    )
  ),
  ", ",
  " & ",
  MAX(1, S5-1)
)}
```

Notes:

- As mention above, the formulae rely on the availability/accuracy of the "No. of Days" cells in order to work correctly.
- These formulae are pretty straightforward:

  - `(MOD(COLUMN($B5:$O5)-COLUMN($B5), 7)>=5)*($B5:$O5>0)` is just an array-formula friendly way of writing `AND((…), (…))`;
  - The only sneaky thing is the use of the `CHOOSE()` function with four nested `IF()`s to select the ordinal indicator.
- Don't forget to **not** include the `{` at the start, and the `}` at the end of the formulae when copy-pasting. These are just used to show that a formula needs to be array-entered.

---

My version of the `TEXTJOIN` UDF:

```
'============================================================================================
' Module     : <any standard module>
' Version    : 0.1.0
' Part       : 1 of 1
' References : Optional - Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5   [VBScript_RegExp_55]
' Source     : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49218794/1961728
'============================================================================================
Public Function TEXTJOIN( _
                                     ByRef delimiter As String, _
                                     ByRef ignore_empty As Boolean, _
                                     ByRef text1 As Variant _
                        ) _
       As String
       Dim ƒ As Excel.WorksheetFunction: Set ƒ = Excel.WorksheetFunction

  Const DELIMITER_ As String = "#"
  Const PATTERN_ As String = "^(?:#)+|(?:#)+$|(#){2,}"

  Static rexDelimiterEscaper As Object ' VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp ' ## Object
  Static rexEmptyIgnorer As Object ' VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp ' ## Object
  If rexEmptyIgnorer Is Nothing _
  Then
    Set rexEmptyIgnorer = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp") ' New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp ' ## CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With rexEmptyIgnorer
      .Global = True
      .Pattern = PATTERN_ ' Replacement = "$1"
    End With
    Set rexDelimiterEscaper = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp") ' New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp ' ## CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With rexDelimiterEscaper
      .Global = True
      .Pattern = "(.)" ' Replacement = "\$1"
    End With
  End If

  Dim varText1 As Variant
  Select Case TypeName(text1)
    Case "Range":
      varText1 = ƒ.Transpose(text1.Value2)
      If text1.Rows.Count = 1 Then
        varText1 = ƒ.Transpose(varText1)
        If text1.Columns.Count = 1 Then varText1 = Array(varText1)
      End If
    Case "Variant()":
      varText1 = text1
    Case Else:
      varText1 = Array(text1)
  End Select
  If ignore_empty _
  Then
    With rexEmptyIgnorer
      .Pattern = Replace(PATTERN_, DELIMITER_, rexDelimiterEscaper.Replace(delimiter, "\$1"))
      TEXTJOIN = .Replace(Join(varText1, delimiter), "$1")
    End With
  Else
    TEXTJOIN = Join(varText1, delimiter)
  End If

End Function
```

Notes:

- This is **not** a proper poly-fill:

  - The first two arguments are not optional;
  - If you no not wish to use a delimiter, you *must* pass an empty string as the first parameter.
  - There is only one other (also required) argument allowed.
- You can pass in anything for the third argument, **except** a multi-dimension array/range. Doing so will result in a `#VALUE!` error.
- It should be very fast, especially for large inputs, as it doesn't use any loops. If you aren't ignoring empty values, it will be lightning fast. Ignoring them will be slower as a couple of regexes and an extra string manipulation have to be used as well.